# Purpose of Virtual width/height in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I watched a video by a guy I think is very good with game development, ForeignGuyMike and in his tutorials he uses a virtual width and height and scales it by 2. Here is a screen shot of the code.
[image: Example Image]

I am starting a brand new game and want to know if there is some type of purpose to this. I want to know the pros and cons of this because I can't seem to find where he explains why and where on the internet someone does this. He then multiplies the virtual width and height by the scale for the size of his window. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go through [this article by Xoppa](http://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/), it should clear your basics. But just to understand by an example.

Say you have a screen of width height = `1980x1020px.` Now in your game, you hardcode your character size be `100px` which looks fine. But if same game is started on a screen of `1280x720px` that character of `100px` height will be too big.

One way is you use relative values always. For example, take height of screen every time game runs and set your character height be `SCREEN_HEIGHT/10`. Now you have to follow this everywhere, set character tail height be `SCREEN_HEIGHT/11.5` and so on. This could be hard to handle once your game starts to grow.

But if you create a screen camera of say `20x11`(virtual screen size) and set character height be `1.2f` then no matter what the screen size be, your character size will always be relative to the ratio of height. Because you are working independently from pixels. Everything is explained in the above article by the way.