# Libgdx box2d issue with dimensions and camera zooming

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, dimensions

I've got a problem with `Box2D`. I'm making a simple 2D game, with a player shooting to enemies. I read that 1 unity in Box2D is equivalent to 1 meter so i should use little dimensions. I set world dimensions to 160x90 but here are the problems:

Using little dimensions i had to zoom my camera that is set to 1280x720 but as you can see there is a big drop of quality in shapes, and also the movements of bodies are no longer flowing. And the max speed is still too slow even if the world steps at 1/300!

`Vsinc` is enabled, zoom is set to 0.125 and the squares you see are 10 units per side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDV7Q.jpg

Here is the code of camera

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(64,32);
```

Here is the code of the class that draw the circle

```
public class JoyCircle implements GraphicalComponent {
public int radius;
public Vector2 position;
ShapeRenderer renderer;
Color color;
OrthographicCamera c;

public JoyCircle(int radius,Vector2 position,OrthographicCamera c,Color color) {
    this.c = c;
    this.color = color;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.position = position;
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(c.combined);
}

@Override
public void update() {

}

@Override
public void draw() {
    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(color);
    renderer.circle(position.x, position.y, radius);
    renderer.end();
}

}

Here is the code of the world draw
public void draw() {
    motionJoystick.draw(); //draws 2 instances of JoyCircle
    renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
}
```

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please turn your question as resolved by choosing correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PPM, i know you might have seen a lot of tutorials using PPM but instead use virtual pixels or potato pixel for camera and box2d. Here read this wonderful [article](http://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857063/purpose-of-virtual-width-height-in-libgdx-java/33857686#33857686). For example:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(20, 11);
```

Here 20 is any arbitrary number for `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` should be actually `WIDTH*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/Gdx.graphics.getWidth()`. 
You don't need to set any zoom level, leave it to default.

Comment: Thank you but i still don't understand how to connect this with Box2D objects, because even if i do not zoom, if the sceen is bigger than camera size, the coords of touches and also phisycs of the game is worst..

Comment: Forget about the actual screen pixel size for a sec and just assume your screen is composed of those virtual points. Now create your game logic based on these points, say if you want your object to move with linear velocity, put it to 0.6f or 1.5f(virtual points) instead of 30 or 40(pixel points). And for screen touch coordinates you can use `camera.unproject()` method to get actual screen coordinates whenever you want.

Comment: For example:                   
 public void render() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  OrthographicCamera c = new OrthographicCamera(64,32);
  ShapeRenderer render = new ShapeRenderer();
  render.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
  render.setProjectionMatrix(c.combined);
  render.circle(5, 5, 10);
  render.end();
 }   the result is this http://imgur.com/8iCOq1a

Comment: Whats wrong in the output? Are you talking about circle edges? Use `render.circle(5, 5, 10, 50); ` method. By they way if you are just demonstrating this than its fine otherwise never create new objects on render method(that's completely off topic for now).

Comment: Ahaha i cannot believe it, the problems were the 4th parameter in circle and the cast to int in the unproject in the touch dragged, that made the circle movement so "angular", sorry for having wasted your time

Comment: No problem. If you have found the answer, either mark one or write one to yourself for others.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use the zoom to handle this 
here what i do and it works very well for me

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH/PPM, Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT/PPM);

// fix camera to the center of the screen
camera.position.set(Config.SCREEN_WIDTH/PPM/2f, Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT/PPM/2f, 0);

camera.update();
```

i put the conversion unit (PPM) to 100

hope this was helpful

Good luck

Comment: I tried but the circle rendered with the ShapeRendered continues to be like the image..

Comment: And the more i increase PPM unit, the more movements are angular

Comment: did you put the camera projection combined to your debugRender like this : debugRendrer.render(world, camera.combined); you need to put more code so we could see how you create body and how you set the parameters

Comment: Edited. The point is that if i decrease the camera size, when i render it into bigger screens (example the desktop config is 1280x720) it only enlarges the screen with loss of graphical and movement quality

Comment: Using PPM is a bad practice, instead use [virtual dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857063/purpose-of-virtual-width-height-in-libgdx-java/33857686#33857686)