# Physics and scale in libGDX with Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have a Image actor in libGDX that has a Body attached and is connected to another Body by a RopeJointDef to simulate a pendulum.
The problem is that the ball is moving very slowly:
[image]

The world gravity is set to -9.81f `b2world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);`
Increasing gravity force change ball speed but I want to be a 'real' simulation. I read in a post that may be because the pixel:meter ratio is 1:1. But I can't figure out how can I change this ratio without ruin the Stage. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Frequency is independent of bob mass: http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/pendulum_equations.htm#.V1BfkfkrIeM.  It only depends on the length of the pendulum and gravity.

Comment: What is world size? You are right about 1:1 thing. Use potato pixel instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021355/libgdx-box2d-porblem-with-dimensions-and-camera-zooming/) and never do physics with screen to box2d  in 1:1 ratio. Box2d doesn't like large numbers, you need to map in virtual pixels or sometimes known as potato pixels.